# How to new a Blob based on the lib.d.ts definition

Tags: typescript

when I try to create a Blob , typescript compiler gives error

```
var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});

Using tsc v1.0.1
error TS7005: Variable 'blob' implicitly has an 'any' type.
error TS2081: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
error TS2085: Could not select overload for 'new' expression.
```

I see the definition in lib.d.ts as

```
declare var Blob: {
    prototype: Blob;
    new (blobParts?: any[], options?: BlobPropertyBag): Blob;
}

interface BlobPropertyBag {
    type?: string;
    endings?: string;
}
```

how to use the new operator based on this definition?
what is the best way to suppress if it is a bug.

### Edit:

it doesn't give an error at typescript playground http://goo.gl/iWCT8B . But, I guess I am using the latest version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should just work. No error with tsc 1.0.1 for me:

[image]

Comment: thanks. my lib.d.ts was actually pointing to an older codeplex git repo. The editor pointed to a newer one, as shown above. it works fine now.